# How to compare file size for copied files in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, copy, filesize

I want to compare the file size of files in folders that have been copied from a folder in my D drive to another folder to make sure the files have been copied correctly.

I'm very new to PowerShell so please forgive my ignorance. I've tried everything to find the answer to this.

```
$Dest = get-childitem '\\\Path2\\Folder*\\*.csv'
$Source = get-childitem 'D:Path1\\Folder*\\*.csv' 
$DestName = $Dest | Select Name
$SourceName = $Source | Select Name
$Source | ForEach-Object{
    $Source.Length -eq $Dest.Length | where-object {$SourceName -Match $DestName }
 }
```

Comment: take a look at >>> `Get-Help New-FileCatalog` <<< that may be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$SourceDir='D:Path1'
$DestinationDir='\\Path2'

$Source = get-childitem "$SourceDir\Folder*" -file "*.csv" -Recurse | select Length, FullName
$Dest = get-childitem "$DestinationDir\Folder*" -file -Filter "*.csv" -Recurse | select Length, @{N='FullName';E={$_.FullName.Replace($DestinationDir, $SourceDir)}}

$Source | ForEach{

$Current=$_
$FileInDest=$Dest | where FullName  -eq $Current.FullName | select -first 1

if ($FileInDest -eq $null)
{
    "File '{0}' not founded in destination dir '{1}'" -f $Current.FullName, $DestinationDir
}
elseif ($Current.Length -ne $FileInDest.Length)
{
    "File '{0}' not same length in destination dir '{1}'" -f $Current.FullName, $DestinationDir
}


}
```

Comment: There's a small typo in there: `$FileInDest=$Des` should be `$FileInDest=$Dest`